# Is it possible to put JQuery inside a JS if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this statement for my application to detect a mobile device, but I want to use JQuery inside my if else statement. I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
window.mobilecheck = function () {            
        var x = document.createElement('link');
        x.rel = "stylesheet";
        x.href = "~/Styles/Default.css";            
        (function (a) {           
            if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $(window).load(function () {

                        $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("display", "block");
                        $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("position", "absolute");
                        $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("margin-top", "-25px");
                        $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("margin-left", "26%;");

                        $("#pwreset").css("margin-left", "50%;");

                        $(".TelerikRadMenu1").css("display", "none");

                        $(".MobileMenu").css("display", "block");

                        $(".TelerikRadMenuItem").css("z-index", "1600001");

                        $(".RadMenuPopup.RadMenuPopup_MetroTouch.MobileMenu.rmHiddenPointer").css("z-index", "160000002");

                        $(".rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000003");

                        $(".rmGroup.rmRootGroup").css("z-index", "160000004");

                        $(".RadMenuPopup.rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000005");

                        $(".RadMenuPopup", ".rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000006");

                        $("#LoggedInTemplate").css("display", "none");

                    });

                });

                }
                x.href = "~/Styles/Mobile.css";                   
            })
                (navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);               
                document.head.appendChild(x);
        };
```

Can someone correct my code in the way that the JQuery is used in the if else or tell me if this is possible/wrong?

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: jQuery methods return normal JS data types, so you absolutely can use a jQuery object in an `if` condition. However, I would advise that browser sniffing in the manner you're using is considered bad practice. I'd suggest you research CSS media queries instead as they are a much more effective solution to what you're doing here

Comment: Yes JQuery is just a library in JS.  Make sure its loaded in the html.

Comment: I used to have a media query at the start of the build of my application, but this does not work in the way that I want it to, so I build this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        var x = document.createElement('link');
        x.rel = "stylesheet";
        x.href = "~/Styles/Default.css";            
        (function (a) {           
            if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {                    

                $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("display", "block");

                $("#pwreset").css("margin-left", "50%;");

                $(".TelerikRadMenu1").css("display", "none");

                $(".MobileMenu").css("display", "block");

                $(".TelerikRadMenuItem").css("z-index", "1600001");

                $(".RadMenuPopup.RadMenuPopup_MetroTouch.MobileMenu.rmHiddenPointer").css("z-index", "160000002");

                $(".rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000003");

                $(".rmGroup.rmRootGroup").css("z-index", "160000004");

                $(".RadMenuPopup.rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000005");

                $(".RadMenuPopup", ".rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000006");

                $("#LoggedInTemplate").css("display", "none");

            }
            x.href = "~/Styles/Mobile.css";                   
        })
            (navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);               
            document.head.appendChild(x);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I have modified your code and encapsulated it with document.ready().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.mobilecheck = function () {            
        var x = document.createElement('link');
        x.rel = "stylesheet";
        x.href = "~/Styles/Default.css";            
        (function (a) {           
            if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {
                $(window).load(function () {

                    $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("display", "block");
                    $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("position", "absolute");
                    $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("margin-top", "-25px");
                    $("#pwreset", "#logout").css("margin-left", "26%;");

                    $("#pwreset").css("margin-left", "50%;");

                    $(".TelerikRadMenu1").css("display", "none");

                    $(".MobileMenu").css("display", "block");

                    $(".TelerikRadMenuItem").css("z-index", "1600001");

                    $(".RadMenuPopup.RadMenuPopup_MetroTouch.MobileMenu.rmHiddenPointer").css("z-index", "160000002");

                    $(".rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000003");

                    $(".rmGroup.rmRootGroup").css("z-index", "160000004");

                    $(".RadMenuPopup.rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000005");

                    $(".RadMenuPopup", ".rmSlide").css("z-index", "160000006");

                    $("#LoggedInTemplate").css("display", "none");

                });
                }
                x.href = "~/Styles/Mobile.css";                   
        })
        (navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);               
        document.head.appendChild(x);
    };
});
```

Also, please check these two links-

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp

Comment: $(document).ready is a jQuery function. And if he only want to include it, when its mobile. You cannot use it to check the document ready state. Or did i not understand the question :-| ?

Comment: It's true what @DomeTune says

Comment: @DomeTune He explicitly asks two things: 1) `Is it possible to put JQuery inside a JS if else statement?` and 2) `Can someone correct my code or tell me if this is possible/wrong?`. There is nothing mentioning he needs to avoid using jQuery outside an IF, so AFAICS this answer is addressing both questions: 1) yes, you can use jQuery inside an IF and 2) he suggests (and I agree) that checking whether the window is ready should be done outside a function. I'd even move the `$(window).load` outside the function as well. If what troubles you is doing it with jQuery, then do it with Javascript.

Comment: @MarcCompte Ok, then i missunderstood the question. I thought the OP only want to use it in the IF-Statement, not outside of it.

Comment: @DomeTune Maybe you are right and he does. I only know what he wrote and he didn't write that jQuery should only be used inside the IF.